# How do I correctly implement this code segment without getting a logic error?

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm making a program that'll allow the user to select a shoe from a premade menu of shoes based on their shoe size, purpose etc. I did this by first creating an abstract class called Shoe that represents a basic shoe. Then I made a bunch of child classes with various names like Nke, Adidas etc. These child classes can instantiate specific shoes of their type, for example Adidas can make a shoe called Adidas Purefly. Then I made a class called Shoebox that, each time its object was instantiated, it would create a menu of all the different shoes. Now I want to make a program that will allow me to select a shoe once a name is passed in, but I have a problem that I will discuss below, after listing all the classes.

This is the Shoe parent class-

```
public abstract class Shoe {

  private String name;
  private int size;
  private String color;
  private String purpose;
  private double price;

  public Shoe (String called, int numSize, String sColor, String Apurpose, double cost ) {
    name=called;
    size=numSize;
    color=sColor;
    purpose=Apurpose;
    price=cost;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return size;
  }

  public double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public String getPurpose() {
    return purpose;
  }

  public String getColor() {
    return color;
  }
}
```

This is the Nike class, an example of a child class that extends Shoe-

```
public class Nike extends Shoe {

  private String name;
  private int size;
  private String color;
  private String purpose;
  private double price;
  private boolean maxGel;

  public Nike(String called, int measurements, String sColor, String purpose, double cost, boolean hasGel) {
    super(called, measurements, sColor, purpose, cost);
    maxGel=hasGel;
  }

  public boolean hasGel() {
    if(maxGel)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
  }
}
```

And this is the Shoebox class, along with an accessor method, that lists all the Shoes using an ArrayList-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Shoebox {

    ArrayList <Shoe> box = new ArrayList<Shoe>();

    public Shoebox() {

    Shoe roshe = new Nike("roshe", new int[]{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "black", "fashion", 129.0, false);
    Shoe trainers= new Nike("trainers",new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},"blue",  "running", 115.5, true);
    Shoe airMax= new Nike("air max", new int[]{8,9,10,11,12,13}, "red", "running",149.9, true);
    Shoe huarache= new Nike("huarache", new int[]{9,10,11,12}, "green", "fashion",139.9, false);
    Shoe stefan= new Nike("stefan", new int[]{3,4,9,10,11,12,15}, "yellow", "tennis",79.9,true);        
    Shoe kd= new Nike("kd", new int[]{5,6,9,10,11,12,14}, "red", "basketball", 145.9, true);
    Shoe lebron= new Nike("lebron", new int[]{6,7,8,9,10}, "gold", "basketball",156.9, true);
    Shoe kyrie= new Nike("kyrie", new int[]{6,7,8,9,10}, "gold", "basketball",156.9, true);
    box.add(roshe);
    box.add(trainers);
    box.add(airMax);
    box.add(huarache);
    box.add(stefan);
    box.add(kd);
    box.add(lebron);
    box.add(kyrie);         //AT this point the length of the box array is 8.



    Shoe harden= new Adidas("harden",new int[]{7,9,10,11,12,13,14}, "red", "basketball", 109.9,  true);
    Shoe lillard= new Adidas("lillard",new int[]{7,9,10,11,12,13,14}, "green", "basketball", 119.9,  true);
    Shoe rose= new Adidas("rose", new int[]{8,9,10},"red", "injury recovery", 145.9, true);
    Shoe nmd= new Adidas("nmd", new int[]{8,10,11,14}, "purple", "fashion", 173.9, true);
    Shoe pharellNMD= new Adidas ("pharell nmd", new int[] {8,9,10,11}, "aqua","fashion", 134.9, true);
    Shoe stanSmith= new Adidas ("stan smith", new int[] {9,10,11,12}, "pink", "skating", 87.9, false);
    Shoe superstar= new Adidas ("superstar",new int[] {9,10,11,12}, "white", "fashion", 79.9, false);
    Shoe barricade= new Adidas ("barricade", new int[] {8,10,11,12,13}, "neon", "tennis", 98.9, false);
    Shoe cloud= new Adidas ("cloud", new int[] {11,12}, "white", "golf", 78.9, false);
    Shoe f7= new Adidas ("f7", new int[] {7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}, "neon", "soccer", 149.9, false);
    box.add(harden);
    box.add(lillard);
    box.add(rose);
    box.add(nmd);
    box.add(pharellNMD);
    box.add(stanSmith);
    box.add(barricade);
    box.add(cloud);
    box.add(f7);


    Shoe suedeloaf= new Armani ("suede loafers", new int[] {9,10,11,12,13}, "black", "fashion", 300.0);
    Shoe colorway= new Armani ("colorway", new int[] {7,8,9,10,11,12,13}, "blue", "fashion", 500.0);
    Shoe purple= new Armani ("purple loafers", new int[] {9,10,12,13}, "black", "fashion", 300.0);
    Shoe transform= new Armani ("transform", new int[] {9,10,11,12,13}, "teal", "formal", 300.0);
    Shoe tang= new Armani ("tang", new int[] {9,10,13}, "pink", "fashion", 300.0);

    box.add(suedeloaf);
    box.add(colorway);
    box.add(purple);
    box.add(transform);
    box.add(tang);


    //At this point the length of the array is 21


    Shoe I = new Jordan ("I", new int[]{8,9,10,11,12,13}, "red", "finesse", 129.9);
    Shoe Iretro = new Jordan ("retro I", new int[] {9,10,11,12}, "red", "finesse", 199.9);
    Shoe II= new Jordan ("II", new int[] {10,11,12,13,14}, "blue", "basketball", 139.9);
    Shoe III= new Jordan ("III", new int[] {9,10,11,11}, "green", "basketball", 149.9);
    Shoe IV = new Jordan ("IV", new int[] {10,11,12,13}, "purple", "basketball", 159.9);
    Shoe VII = new Jordan ("VII", new int[] {10,11,12,13}, "yellow", "basketball", 189.9);
    Shoe VIII = new Jordan ("VIII", new int[] {10,11,12,13,14}, "blue", "fashion", 189.9);
    Shoe XI= new Jordan ("XI", new int[] {11,12,13}, "red", "basketball", 199.9);
    Shoe XII= new Jordan ("XII", new int[] {9,10,11,12}, "navy", "basketball", 239.9);

    box.add(I);
    box.add(Iretro);
    box.add(II);
    box.add(III);
    box.add(IV);
    box.add(VII);
    box.add(VIII);
    box.add(XI);
    box.add(XII);

    //The length of the box array at this point 30

    Shoe can= new Dockers ("cambridge", new int[] {9,10,11,12,13,14}, "navy", "formal", 64.9);
    Shoe bean= new Dockers ("bean", new int[] {10,11,12,13}, "green", "formal", 77.0);
    Shoe tang1= new Dockers ("tang", new int[] {12,13,14}, "orange", "fashion", 69.9);
    Shoe gold= new Dockers ("gold", new int[] {9,10,11,12,13,14}, "gold", "formal", 62.9);
    Shoe grizzly= new Dockers ("grizzly", new int[] {9,10,11}, "grey", "teaching", 89.9);

    box.add(can);
    box.add(bean);
    box.add(tang1);
    box.add(gold);
    box.add(grizzly);

    //The length of the box array at this point is 35

    Shoe AI= new Reebok("AI", new int[] {8,9,10,11}, "grey", "basketball", 140.0);
    Shoe shaq= new Reebok ("shaq", new int[] {14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}, "grey", "basketball", 220.0);
    Shoe pumpGraphite= new Reebok("pump graphite", new int[] {7,8,9,10,11}, "orange", "running", 129.9);
    Shoe BB= new Reebok("BB", new int[] {8,9,10,11}, "red", "running", 138.0);
    Shoe leathWhite= new Reebok("leather whites", new int[] {8,9,10,11}, "white", "fashion", 170.0);
    Shoe dualPumpRunner= new Reebok("dual pump runner", new int[] {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "grey", "running", 130.0);
    Shoe kamikaze2= new Reebok("kamikaze 2", new int[] {8,9,10,11}, "black", "basketball", 140.0);
    Shoe shagnosis= new Reebok("shagnosis", new int[] {14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}, "zebra", "basketball", 240.0);
    Shoe question= new Reebok("question", new int[] {8,9,10,11}, "grey", "basketball", 140.0);


    box.add(AI);
    box.add(shaq);
    box.add(pumpGraphite);
    box.add(BB);
    box.add(leathWhite);
    box.add(dualPumpRunner);
    box.add(kamikaze2);
    box.add(shagnosis);
    box.add(question);

    //The length of the box array at this point is 44
    }

    public ArrayList<Shoe> getShoes()
    {
        return this.box;
    }


}
```

And finally this is the code I have so far for the Runner Class, ShoeSelector (keep in mind that i am not done yet)-

```
import java.util.*;
public class ShoeSelector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner name= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner size= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner color= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner priceMax= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner priceMin= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner purpose= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner side = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Do you know what shoe you want?     If you know the name, enter the name     If you don't, enter 0");
        String nom= name.nextLine();

        Shoebox yee= new Shoebox();  //Creates a new Shoebox array that contains all the shoes

        if (!(nom.equals(0))){  //Checks to see if you have entered a shoe name
        for (Shoe e: yee.getShoes()){
            if (e.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nom)){
                System.out.println("Good News! We have the Shoe brand you are looking for. Here are the details of " +nom);
                System.out.println( "name:   " + e.getName() +"    color:   " + e.getColor()+"    purpose:   " +e.getPurpose()+"   cost:   " + e.getPrice());
                System.out.println("Do you want to search another model?    Y/N");
                String what= side.nextLine();

                if (what.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){

                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }
//          else {
//              System.out.println("We are very sorry, but we are not in possesseion of this model currently. But please return to check back.");
//              System.out.println("Do you want to search another model?    Y/N");
//              String what= side.nextLine();
//              
//              if (what.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
//              {
//                  nom= name.nextLine();
//              }
//                  
//
//          }
        }
    }


    }
}
```

So far, this class is supposed to read in any name of the shoe that the user provides and if there does exist a shoe with the same name, then it should return all the info about the shoe. And if there is no such shoe, then it's supposed to ask if the user wants to search for another shoe.

Okay, so the problem is, that if you run the uncommented section,it does give you the details of the shoe if it does exist, but I can't figure out how to search for another shoe if the user inputs 'y' for if he/she wants another search.

Also, if I uncomment out the commented section, when I run the program, it says that no shoe could be found even if there is a shoe of the same name.

Can someone please explain to me why it does not work and how to fix it?

Thank You Very Much

P.S. Please remember that I am a beginner at this, so I am not very well versed in the language, so if you find my question stupid, please don't dislike it. Instead comment and tell me where I was wrong.

Comment: What's the error message? What do you mean with 'does not work'?

Comment: You are missing quotes in your code for 'String' types. What is the error?

Comment: It should be ``new Nike("roshe", 11, "black", "fashion", 129.0, false)``

Comment: this line
`Shoe roshe = new Nike(roshe, 11, black, fashion, 129.0, false)`
expects strings in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shoe roshe = new Nike("roshe", 11, "black", "fashion", 129.0, false)
```

String literals should be enclosed in double quotes.

As for your change in size type, pass int array instead of int

```
int s[] = {11,12,13};
Shoe roshe = new Nike("roshe", s, "black", "fashion", 129.0, false)

or

Shoe roshe = new Nike("roshe",new int[]{11, 12, 13} , "black", "fashion", 129.0, false)
```

Comment: @f1sh Edited that thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, man...it works now.

Comment: Glad to help. Do accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I changed the program for Shoes

Comment: Instead of this-public abstract class Shoe {

  private String name;
  private int size;
  private String color;
  private String purpose;
  private double price;

  public Shoe (String called, int numSize, String sColor, String Apurpose, double cost ) {
    name=called;
    size=numSize;
    color=sColor;
    purpose=Apurpose;
    price=cost;
  }

Comment: It reads        public abstract class Shoe {
 
 private String name;
 private int[] size;
 private String color;
 private String purpose;
 private double price;
 
 public Shoe (String called, int []numSize, String sColor, String Apurpose, double cost )
 {
  name=called;
  size=numSize;
  color=sColor;
  purpose=Apurpose;
  price=cost;
 }

Comment: So I changed int size in 'Shoes' to int[] size.

Comment: And I changed nike to      public class Nike extends Shoe
{

 private String name;
 private int[] size;
 private String color;
 private String purpose;
 private double price;
 private boolean maxGel;
 
 public Nike(String called, int[] measurements, String sColor, String purpose, double cost, boolean hasGel) {
  super(called, measurements, sColor, purpose, cost);
  maxGel=hasGel;
 }

Comment: Is there any problem you are running into while doing all these things?

Comment: Oh yeah I just can't figure out how to instantiate the object with array as a parameter

Comment: I edited my answer have a look

Comment: Thank you very much but is there any direct way to put the array in the constructor?

Comment: Yes there is , I edited the answer have a look

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help so far, but is there any way you can help me with the edited question above?

Comment: You could write a menu-driven loop for providing options to user.